# Prolog: list of numbers

Tags: list, prolog

How can I generate a list of numbers from 1 to N, where N >= 0?

Predicate: numbers(N, L).

```
?-­ numbers(5,X).

X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?­- numbers(0,X).

X = [].
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Whenever lists are involved, you must divide the problem into a base case and an inductive case. Can you do that?

Answer (score 17):

Use the built-in `numlist/3`:

```
?- numlist(1, 5, L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?- numlist(1, 0, L).
false.
```

In SWI-Prolog you can use `listing(numlist)` to see how it has been implemented.

Note that `numlist/3` will never generate an empty list. If you want that, then you need to write a simple wrapper that maps failure to an empty list.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `between` to generate integers between to endpoints and then `findall` to collect them together. Try this predicate -

```
numbers(Count, List) :-
    findall(N, between(1,Count,N), List).
```

If you give Count anything <=0, between fails and this predicate will generate the empty list.